# How to view saved Docker Logs from a terminal, color parsed and formatted the same way as Docker Logs shows it?

Tags: docker, logging, encoding, character-encoding, docker-compose

When I run `docker logs container` or `docker-compose -f file.yml logs -f` I get a nicely formatted, color parsed view of the log. It handles all the `\t \n` from my script and shows them as Tabs and New lines. In addition, using `chalk`, docker outputs the text in colors as specified.

To find the log, I run `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' container_1`

Which results in `/var/lib/docker/containers/longid/longid-json.log`

However, upon saving the file, My nice docker view of this

[image]

Turns into this (viewed in a terminal from `cat log.json.txt`)

[image]

I get that it's using the `json-file` logging driver, but it also appears to mess up the encoding and changes to some ascii format with `\uxxxx` all over the place.

I tried running the file through `ascii2uni` and got this

[image]

Which got me most of the way there, but it still has some leftover `\r\n` and also, the problem of it appearing as a JSON file.

So my question is this:

How do I view the file like docker does when running `docker logs`, with UTF8 encoding, formatted, and with color parsed output? Can I run `docker logs myfile.log.txt` and read straight from a given file?